# Shower needs turning too far to turn off and drips constantly

Tags: bathroom, shower, bathroom-fixtures

Hoping someone can assist here.

Have had this shower for around a year. The on/off is a round knob to twist with a smaller temperature dial inside that.
Anyway, when we turn the shower off, we have to really turn it to the point that it becomes stiff. There is no stop point and you can keep turning it and eventually with enough force, the water stops.

Went and bought a replacement today as the dripping had gotten really bad and no amount of turning would stop the water. Replaced the shower with a new identical version and already it seems the issue is going to persist.

I have just had a shower there and to turn it off I had to turn it past the point where it begins to get stiff to turn (where you would assume it would turn off) I didnt want to turn it too far at first so I didn't but have had to return 10 minutes later as it was constantly dripping. Turned it some more and the water stopped but it really feels like it's too tight.

Does anyone have any advice on this please? Showers arent cheap and I really dont want this to get damaged by over tightening.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Pix would be great. There are too many different kinds of shower faucets to diagnose without.

Comment: The shower in question is this https://www.screwfix.com/p/triton-verne-rear-fed-exposed-chrome-thermostatic-mixer-shower-flexible/69513

Comment: Is it on a high pressure feed? If so, have you fitted the flow regulator?